# mysqld process performance

Tags: mysql, performance, configuration, mysqld

I'm running in problems that I can't solve by myself. Mysqld process go over 100%, sometimes over 500% in web peaks. Idk why mysql running only one process, websites works fast without any problem with db, but the server is on fire :)

Thanks for help.

**Glances screenshot**

[image]

**PMA stats**

[image]

**Mysql conf**

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#
user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                  = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#port                   = 3306
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/share/mysql
#skip-external-locking

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
#key_buffer_size        = 16M
#max_allowed_packet     = 16M
#thread_stack           = 192K
#thread_cache_size      = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
#myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit      = 3M
query_cache_size       = 512M

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file       = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log            = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time        = 10
log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
log_slow_verbosity     = query_plan
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
#max_binlog_size        = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = exclude_database_name

#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
#chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates you can use for example the GUI tool "tinyca".
#
#ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/cacert.pem
#ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
#ssl-key = /etc/mysql/server-key.pem
#
# Accept only connections using the latest and most secure TLS protocol version.
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with OpenSSL:
#ssl-cipher = TLSv1.2
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with YaSSL (default in Debian):
#ssl = on

#
# * Character sets
#
# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
#
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!

#
# * Unix socket authentication plugin is built-in since 10.0.22-6
#
# Needed so the root database user can authenticate without a password but
# only when running as the unix root user.
#
# Also available for other users if required.
# See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.3 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.3]
```

**innodb status**

```
=====================================
2021-05-18 07:28:40 0x7fa254ae1700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 20 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 0 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 2071 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 2071
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 91905
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 308896
RW-shared spins 30399106, rounds 62424994, OS waits 24849
RW-excl spins 70580, rounds 75923, OS waits 1236
RW-sx spins 2, rounds 31, OS waits 1
Spin rounds per wait: 2.05 RW-shared, 1.08 RW-excl, 15.50 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 702288838
Purge done for trx's n:o < 702288838 undo n:o < 0 state: running
History list length 4
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421810504249608, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421810504258040, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 0
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 3939, OS thread handle 140334839383808, query id 240725 localhost xxx Sending data
SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE `country` = 'cz' and `status` = 1 and `hidden` = 0 and `producer_text` = 'Opel' and `source` = '351' and `id` != '129774' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 702288838, sees < 702288838
---TRANSACTION 421810504253824, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421810504245392, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
112634734 OS file reads, 21796 OS file writes, 13046 OS fsyncs
1 pending reads, 0 pending writes
38857.36 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 9.55 writes/s, 4.55 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 20, seg size 22, 3 merges
merged operations:
insert 3, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 16 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
0.50 hash searches/s, 5.45 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 18286288975
Log flushed up to   18286288953
Pages flushed up to 18286288408
Last checkpoint at  18286288339
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
6692 log i/o's done, 2.70 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 170655744
Dictionary memory allocated 274160
Buffer pool size   8192
Free buffers       0
Database pages     8168
Old database pages 3003
Modified db pages  4
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.049
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 1
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1447105, not young 960198976
0.00 youngs/s, 371282.29 non-youngs/s
Pages read 112634979, created 220, written 12713
38857.26 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 6.30 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 928 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 685 / 1000
Pages read ahead 2432.43/s, evicted without access 182.74/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 8168, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[1644666]:cur[15020], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=15562, Main thread ID=140334759667456, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 1556, updated 704, deleted 113, read 2705916905
0.70 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 1027711.31 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

**Global status**

```
Aborted_clients 0   
Aborted_connects    7   
Access_denied_errors    6   
Acl_column_grants   0   
Acl_database_grants 16  
Acl_function_grants 0   
Acl_procedure_grants    0   
Acl_package_spec_grants 0   
Acl_package_body_grants 0   
Acl_proxy_users 1   
Acl_role_grants 0   
Acl_roles   0   
Acl_table_grants    0   
Acl_users   17  
Aria_pagecache_blocks_not_flushed   0   
Aria_pagecache_blocks_unused    15706   
Aria_pagecache_blocks_used  1755    
Aria_pagecache_read_requests    328323  
Aria_pagecache_reads    5310    
Aria_pagecache_write_requests   108520  
Aria_pagecache_writes   108520  
Aria_transaction_log_syncs  49  
Binlog_commits  0   
Binlog_group_commits    0   
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_count   0   
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_lock_wait   0   
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_timeout 0   
Binlog_snapshot_file        
Binlog_snapshot_position    0   
Binlog_bytes_written    0   
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0   
Binlog_cache_use    0   
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0   
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0   
Busy_time   0.000000    
Bytes_received  32955992    
Bytes_sent  2811242294  
Column_compressions 0   
Column_decompressions   0   
Com_admin_commands  0   
Com_alter_db    0   
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0   
Com_alter_event 0   
Com_alter_function  0   
Com_alter_procedure 0   
Com_alter_server    0   
Com_alter_sequence  0   
Com_alter_table 0   
Com_alter_tablespace    0   
Com_alter_user  0   
Com_analyze 0   
Com_assign_to_keycache  0   
Com_begin   0   
Com_binlog  0   
Com_call_procedure  0   
Com_change_db   2377    
Com_change_master   0   
Com_check   0   
Com_checksum    0   
Com_commit  0   
Com_compound_sql    0   
Com_create_db   0   
Com_create_event    0   
Com_create_function 0   
Com_create_index    0   
Com_create_package  0   
Com_create_package_body 0   
Com_create_procedure    0   
Com_create_role 0   
Com_create_sequence 0   
Com_create_server   0   
Com_create_table    0   
Com_create_temporary_table  0   
Com_create_trigger  0   
Com_create_udf  0   
Com_create_user 0   
Com_create_view 0   
Com_dealloc_sql 0   
Com_delete  102 
Com_delete_multi    0   
Com_do  0   
Com_drop_db 0   
Com_drop_event  0   
Com_drop_function   0   
Com_drop_index  0   
Com_drop_procedure  0   
Com_drop_package    0   
Com_drop_package_body   0   
Com_drop_role   0   
Com_drop_server 0   
Com_drop_sequence   0   
Com_drop_table  0   
Com_drop_temporary_table    0   
Com_drop_trigger    0   
Com_drop_user   0   
Com_drop_view   0   
Com_empty_query 0   
Com_execute_immediate   0   
Com_execute_sql 0   
Com_flush   0   

Com_get_diagnostics 0   
Com_grant   0   
Com_grant_role  0   
Com_ha_close    0   
Com_ha_open 0   
Com_ha_read 0   
Com_help    0   
Com_insert  1445    
Com_insert_select   0   
Com_install_plugin  0   
Com_kill    0   
Com_load    0   
Com_lock_tables 0   
Com_multi   0   
Com_optimize    0   
Com_preload_keys    0   
Com_prepare_sql 0   
Com_purge   0   
Com_purge_before_date   0   
Com_release_savepoint   0   
Com_rename_table    0   
Com_rename_user 0   
Com_repair  0   
Com_replace 0   
Com_replace_select  0   
Com_reset   0   
Com_resignal    0   
Com_revoke  0   
Com_revoke_all  0   
Com_revoke_role 0   
Com_rollback    0   
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0   
Com_savepoint   0   
Com_select  130176  
Com_set_option  7437    
Com_show_authors    0   
Com_show_binlog_events  0   
Com_show_binlogs    0   
Com_show_charsets   0   
Com_show_collations 0   
Com_show_contributors   0   
Com_show_create_db  0   
Com_show_create_event   0   
Com_show_create_func    0   
Com_show_create_package 0   
Com_show_create_package_body    0   
Com_show_create_proc    0   
Com_show_create_table   0   
Com_show_create_trigger 0   
Com_show_create_user    0   
Com_show_databases  0   
Com_show_engine_logs    0   
Com_show_engine_mutex   0   
Com_show_engine_status  1   
Com_show_errors 0   
Com_show_events 0   
Com_show_explain    0   
Com_show_fields 3706    
Com_show_function_status    0   
Com_show_generic    0   
Com_show_grants 0   
Com_show_keys   48  
Com_show_master_status  126 
Com_show_open_tables    0   
Com_show_package_status 0   
Com_show_package_body_status    0   
Com_show_plugins    0   
Com_show_privileges 0   
Com_show_procedure_status   0   
Com_show_processlist    91  
Com_show_profile    0   
Com_show_profiles   0   
Com_show_relaylog_events    0   
Com_show_slave_hosts    0   
Com_show_slave_status   126 
Com_show_status 170 
Com_show_storage_engines    0   
Com_show_table_status   0   
Com_show_tables 1   
Com_show_triggers   0   
Com_show_variables  149 
Com_show_warnings   2   
Com_shutdown    0   
Com_signal  0   
Com_start_all_slaves    0   
Com_start_slave 0   
Com_stmt_close  0   
Com_stmt_execute    0   
Com_stmt_fetch  0   
Com_stmt_prepare    0   
Com_stmt_reprepare  0   
Com_stmt_reset  0   
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0   
Com_stop_all_slaves 0   
Com_stop_slave  0   
Com_truncate    0   
Com_uninstall_plugin    0   
Com_unlock_tables   0   
Com_update  79463   
Com_update_multi    0   

Com_xa_commit   0   
Com_xa_end  0   
Com_xa_prepare  0   
Com_xa_recover  0   
Com_xa_rollback 0   
Com_xa_start    0   
Compression OFF 
Connection_errors_accept    0   
Connection_errors_internal  0   
Connection_errors_max_connections   0   
Connection_errors_peer_address  0   
Connection_errors_select    0   
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0   
Connections 3702    
Cpu_time    0.000000    
Created_tmp_disk_tables 5310    
Created_tmp_files   5   
Created_tmp_tables  6267    
Delayed_errors  0   
Delayed_insert_threads  0   
Delayed_writes  0   
Delete_scan 34  
Empty_queries   22185   
Executed_events 0   
Executed_triggers   0   
Feature_check_constraint    0   
Feature_custom_aggregate_functions  0   
Feature_delay_key_write 0   
Feature_dynamic_columns 0   
Feature_fulltext    0   
Feature_gis 0   
Feature_invisible_columns   0   
Feature_json    0   
Feature_locale  142 
Feature_subquery    139 
Feature_system_versioning   0   
Feature_timezone    0   
Feature_trigger 0   
Feature_window_functions    0   
Feature_xml 0   
Flush_commands  1   
Handler_commit  108826  
Handler_delete  103 
Handler_discover    0   
Handler_external_lock   0   
Handler_icp_attempts    14767   
Handler_icp_match   14764   
Handler_mrr_init    0   
Handler_mrr_key_refills 0   
Handler_mrr_rowid_refills   0   
Handler_prepare 0   
Handler_read_first  1899    
Handler_read_key    90853   
Handler_read_last   587 
Handler_read_next   196570228   
Handler_read_prev   5958699 
Handler_read_retry  0   
Handler_read_rnd    23321   
Handler_read_rnd_deleted    2   
Handler_read_rnd_next   2320508904  
Handler_rollback    27  
Handler_savepoint   0   
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0   
Handler_tmp_delete  0   
Handler_tmp_update  6   
Handler_tmp_write   452577  
Handler_update  79571   
Handler_write   1445    
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status      
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210518  6:54:02    
Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status        
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_incomplete  OFF 
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   8169    
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   133840896   
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  4   
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  65536   
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    10792   
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   0   
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   23  
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  8192    
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0   
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   5192384 
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   673851  
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    1304826605  
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    100447238   
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    174313  
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   20725   
Innodb_data_fsyncs  12305   
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0   
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0   
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0   
Innodb_data_read    1730815887872   
Innodb_data_reads   105640389   
Innodb_data_writes  20461   
Innodb_data_written 395168256   
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  11792   
Innodb_dblwr_writes 2306    
Innodb_log_waits    0   
Innodb_log_write_requests   4286    
Innodb_log_writes   4620    

Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    6228    
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0   
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0   
Innodb_os_log_written   5798400 
Innodb_page_size    16384   
Innodb_pages_created    215 
Innodb_pages_read   105640616   
Innodb_pages0_read  106 
Innodb_pages_written    11923   
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0   
Innodb_row_lock_time    7   
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    3   
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    6   
Innodb_row_lock_waits   2   
Innodb_rows_deleted 103 
Innodb_rows_inserted    1445    
Innodb_rows_read    2522664847  
Innodb_rows_updated 689 
Innodb_system_rows_deleted  0   
Innodb_system_rows_inserted 0   
Innodb_system_rows_read 0   
Innodb_system_rows_updated  0   
Innodb_num_open_files   109 
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0   
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128 
Innodb_undo_truncations 0   
Innodb_page_compression_saved   0   
Innodb_num_index_pages_written  0   
Innodb_num_non_index_pages_written  0   
Innodb_num_pages_page_compressed    0   
Innodb_num_page_compressed_trim_op  0   
Innodb_num_pages_page_decompressed  0   
Innodb_num_pages_page_compression_error 0   
Innodb_num_pages_encrypted  0   
Innodb_num_pages_decrypted  0   
Innodb_have_lz4 ON  
Innodb_have_lzo OFF 
Innodb_have_lzma    OFF 
Innodb_have_bzip2   OFF 
Innodb_have_snappy  ON  
Innodb_have_punch_hole  ON  
Innodb_defragment_compression_failures  0   
Innodb_defragment_failures  0   
Innodb_defragment_count 0   
Innodb_instant_alter_column 0   
Innodb_onlineddl_rowlog_rows    0   
Innodb_onlineddl_rowlog_pct_used    0   
Innodb_onlineddl_pct_progress   0   
Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads  17047   
Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads_avo...   0   
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_read_from_cache    0   
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_read_from_disk 0   
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_modified   0   
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_flushed    0   
Innodb_encryption_rotation_estimated_iops   0   
Innodb_encryption_key_rotation_list_length  0   
Innodb_encryption_n_merge_blocks_encrypted  0   
Innodb_encryption_n_merge_blocks_decrypted  0   
Innodb_encryption_n_rowlog_blocks_encrypted 0   
Innodb_encryption_n_rowlog_blocks_decrypted 0   
Innodb_encryption_n_temp_blocks_encrypted   0   
Innodb_encryption_n_temp_blocks_decrypted   0   
Innodb_scrub_background_page_reorganizations    0   
Innodb_scrub_background_page_splits 0   
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_underf...   0   
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_out_of...   0   
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_missin...   0   
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_unknow...   0   
Innodb_scrub_log    0   
Innodb_encryption_num_key_requests  0   
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0   
Key_blocks_unused   107162  
Key_blocks_used 1   
Key_blocks_warm 0   
Key_read_requests   18  
Key_reads   1   
Key_write_requests  0   
Key_writes  0   
Last_query_cost 0.000000    
Master_gtid_wait_count  0   
Master_gtid_wait_time   0   
Master_gtid_wait_timeouts   0   
Max_statement_time_exceeded 0   
Max_used_connections    24  
Memory_used 817596480   
Memory_used_initial 809934208   
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0   
Open_files  27  
Open_streams    0   
Open_table_definitions  120 
Open_tables 165 
Opened_files    21443   
Opened_plugin_libraries 0   
Opened_table_definitions    119 
Opened_tables   171 
Opened_views    0   
Performance_schema_accounts_lost    0   
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0   
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0   
Performance_schema_digest_lost  0   

Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0   
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0   
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0   
Performance_schema_hosts_lost   0   
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0   
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0   
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0   
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0   
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0   
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0   
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost  0   
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost    0   
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost   0   
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost   0   
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0   
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0   
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0   
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0   
Performance_schema_users_lost   0   
Prepared_stmt_count 0   
Qcache_free_blocks  903 
Qcache_free_memory  489504208   
Qcache_hits 98707   
Qcache_inserts  25058   
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0   
Qcache_not_cached   6619    
Qcache_queries_in_cache 13668   
Qcache_total_blocks 28525   
Queries 229107  
Questions   229107  
Rows_read   2522113042  
Rows_sent   14378120    
Rows_tmp_read   458710  
Rpl_semi_sync_master_clients    0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_get_ack    0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_net_avg_wait_time  0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_net_wait_time  0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_net_waits  0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_no_times   0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_no_tx  0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_request_ack    0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_status OFF 
Rpl_semi_sync_master_timefunc_failures  0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_tx_avg_wait_time   0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_tx_wait_time   0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_tx_waits   0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_wait_pos_backtraverse  0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_wait_sessions  0   
Rpl_semi_sync_master_yes_tx 0   
Rpl_semi_sync_slave_send_ack    0   
Rpl_semi_sync_slave_status  OFF 
Rpl_status  AUTH_MASTER 
Rpl_transactions_multi_engine   0   
Select_full_join    180 
Select_full_range_join  0   
Select_range    1662    
Select_range_check  0   
Select_scan 23758   
Slave_connections   0   
Slave_heartbeat_period  0.000   
Slave_open_temp_tables  0   
Slave_received_heartbeats   0   
Slave_retried_transactions  0   
Slave_running   OFF 
Slave_skipped_errors    0   
Slaves_connected    0   
Slaves_running  0   
Slow_launch_threads 0   
Slow_queries    0   
Sort_merge_passes   0   
Sort_priority_queue_sorts   1627    
Sort_range  339 
Sort_rows   23495   
Sort_scan   3369    
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0   
Ssl_accepts 0   
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0   
Ssl_cipher      
Ssl_cipher_list     
Ssl_client_connects 0   
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0   
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0   
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0   
Ssl_default_timeout 0   
Ssl_finished_accepts    0   
Ssl_finished_connects   0   
Ssl_server_not_after        
Ssl_server_not_before       
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0   
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0   
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE    
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0   
Ssl_session_cache_size  0   
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0   
Ssl_sessions_reused 0   
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0   
Ssl_verify_depth    0   
Ssl_verify_mode 0   
Ssl_version     
Subquery_cache_hit  0   

Subquery_cache_miss 0   
Syncs   100 
Table_locks_immediate   132 
Table_locks_waited  0   
Table_open_cache_active_instances   1   
Table_open_cache_hits   114847  
Table_open_cache_misses 371 
Table_open_cache_overflows  0   
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0   
Tc_log_page_size    4096    
Tc_log_page_waits   0   
Threadpool_idle_threads 0   
Threadpool_threads  0   
Threads_cached  19  
Threads_connected   5   
Threads_created 24  
Threads_running 8   
Transactions_gtid_foreign_engine    0   
Transactions_multi_engine   0   
Update_scan 441 
Uptime  1918    
Uptime_since_flush_status   1918    
wsrep_applier_thread_count  0   
wsrep_cluster_conf_id   18446744073709551615    
wsrep_cluster_size  0   
wsrep_cluster_state_uuid        
wsrep_cluster_status    Disconnected    
wsrep_connected OFF 
wsrep_local_bf_aborts   0   
wsrep_local_index   18446744073709551615    
wsrep_provider_name     
wsrep_provider_vendor       
wsrep_provider_version      
wsrep_ready OFF 
wsrep_rollbacker_thread_count   0   
wsrep_thread_count  0
```

**Server info**

- Debian 10
- 6 core CPU
- 16 Gb ram

Comment: `GLOBAL STATUS` is nice, but useless without `SHOW VARIABLES` also.

Comment: @RickJames sorry cant edit original post, here is show variables response https://gist.github.com/thiscodeworks/5ca4825a8e6829b79e4ddfb2778d2e1f thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:
```

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.3.25-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
- 15.7 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 00:31:58; Please rerun SHOW GLOBAL STATUS after several hours.
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

Apparently you have a small amount of data.  If you expect to grow much past 128M, it would be wise to increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, but not past 11G.

If the disk is SSD, change innodb_io_capacity to 1000.

read_buffer_size = 512M

Set `long_query_time = 1` and turn on the slowlog.

Lower query_cache_size to 50M -- it is a CPU hog, without that much benefit.

**Details and other observations:**

`( Key_blocks_used * 1024 / key_buffer_size ) = 1 * 1024 / 128M = 0.00%` -- Percent of key_buffer used. High-water-mark.
-- Lower key_buffer_size (now 134217728) to avoid unnecessary memory usage.

`( (key_buffer_size / 0.20 + innodb_buffer_pool_size / 0.70) ) = ((128M / 0.20 + 128M / 0.70)) / 16857746636.8 = 5.1%` -- Most of available ram should be made available for caching.
-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

`( ( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) / innodb_io_capacity / Uptime ) = ( 1 + 0 + 105640616 + 11923 + 2306 + 10792 ) / 200 / 1918 = 27545.8%` -- This *may* be a metric indicating what innodb_io_capacity is set reasonably.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 200) if the hardware can handle it.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 128M` -- InnoDB Data + Index cache
-- 128M (an old default) is woefully small.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 128 / 16857746636.8 = 0.80%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool
-- Set to about 70% of available RAM. (To low is less efficient; too high risks swapping.)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- When flushing, use this many IOPs.
-- Reads could be slugghish or spiky.

`( innodb_io_capacity_max / innodb_io_capacity ) = 2,000 / 200 = 10` -- Capacity: max/plain
-- Recommend 2. Max should be about equal to the IOPs your I/O subsystem can handle. (If the drive type is unknown 2000/200 may be a reasonable pair.)

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_reads / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests ) = 100,447,238 / 1304826605 = 7.7%` -- Read requests that had to hit disk
-- Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 134217728) if you have enough RAM.

`( Innodb_pages_read / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests ) = 105,640,616 / 1304826605 = 8.1%` -- Read requests that had to hit disk
-- Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 134217728) if you have enough RAM.

`( Innodb_pages_written / Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests ) = 11,923 / 20725 = 57.5%` -- Write requests that had to hit disk
-- Check innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 134217728)

`( innodb_flush_method ) = innodb_flush_method = fsync` -- How InnoDB should ask the OS to write blocks. Suggest O_DIRECT or O_ALL_DIRECT (Percona) to avoid double buffering. (At least for Unix.) See chrischandler for caveat about O_ALL_DIRECT

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( ( Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written ) / Uptime / innodb_io_capacity ) = ( 105640616 + 11923 ) / 1918 / 200 = 27542.4%` -- If > 100%, need more io_capacity.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 200) if the drives can handle it.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster. 0 is OK for Galera.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( (Com_show_create_table + Com_show_fields) / Questions ) = (0 + 3706) / 229107 = 1.6%` -- Naughty framework -- spending a lot of effort rediscovering the schema.
-- Complain to the 3rd party vendor.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( query_cache_size ) = 512M` -- Size of QC
-- Too small = not of much use. Too large = too much overhead. Recommend either 0 or no more than 50M.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 5,310 / 6267 = 84.7%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Maybe increase tmp_table_size (now 16777216) and max_heap_table_size (now 16777216); improve indexes; avoid blobs, etc.

`( Handler_read_rnd_next / Com_select ) = 2,320,508,904 / 130176 = 17,825` -- Avg rows scanned per SELECT. (approx)
-- Consider raising read_buffer_size (now 131072)

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Uptime_since_flush_status ) = 1,918 = 31m 58s` -- How long (in seconds) since FLUSH STATUS (or server startup).
-- GLOBAL STATUS has not been gathered long enough to get reliable suggestions for many of the issues. Fix what you can, then come back in a several hours.

`( Uptime ) = 1,918 = 31m 58s` -- How long (in seconds) the server has been running.
-- The system has not been up long enough to get reliable suggestions for many of the issues. Fix what you can, then come back with fresh values after the system has been running several hours.

`( Max_used_connections / max_connections ) = 24 / 151 = 15.9%` -- Peak % of connections
-- Since several memory factors can expand based on max_connections (now 151), it is good not to have that setting too high.

`( thread_cache_size / Max_used_connections ) = 151 / 24 = 629.2%`
-- There is no advantage in having the thread cache bigger than your likely number of connections. Wasting space is the disadvantage.

**Abnormally small:**

```
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests / (Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests + Innodb_buffer_pool_reads ) = 92.9%
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed = 1.92
aria_checkpoint_log_activity = 1.05e+6
aria_pagecache_buffer_size = 128MB
eq_range_index_dive_limit = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = 128MB
innodb_max_undo_log_size = 10MB
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size = 128MB
innodb_sort_buffer_size = 1.05e+6
innodb_spin_wait_delay = 4
lock_wait_timeout = 86,400
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
( Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written ) / Uptime = 55,084
Handler_read_next / Handler_read_key = 2,163
Handler_read_rnd_next / Handler_read_rnd = 99,502
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads * innodb_page_size / innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1226162.6%
Memory_used_initial = 8.1e+8
Qcache_free_memory = 466.8MB
Tc_log_page_size = 4,096
aria_sort_buffer_size = 256.0MB
log_slow_rate_limit = 1,000
max_relay_log_size = 1024MB
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
Innodb_have_snappy = ON
aria_recover_options = BACKUP,QUICK
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
lc_messages = cs_CZ
log_slow_admin_statements = ON
log_slow_verbosity = query_plan
myisam_stats_method = NULLS_UNEQUAL
old_alter_table = DEFAULT
```

Comment: Thanks for huge feedback! What you mean with "Apparently you have a small amount of data" the disk is ssd but have right now only 17gb available. I rerunned the global status with longer uptime if that help more somehow https://gist.github.com/thiscodeworks/e7feb233b30eb7cda04846fdd62db835. Thanks for future report. I just editing innodb_buffer_pool_size, its in bytes default 134217728 .. so if I want to change it to 8Gb its 8589934592 .. just double checking. Thanks.

Comment: Use this to find out how much data you have:   `SELECT  ENGINE,
        ROUND(SUM(data_length) /1024/1024, 1) AS "Data MB",
        ROUND(SUM(index_length)/1024/1024, 1) AS "Index MB",
        ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024, 1) AS "Total MB",
        COUNT(*) "Num Tables"
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE  table_schema not in ("information_schema", "PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA", "SYS_SCHEMA", "ndbinfo", "sys")
    GROUP BY  ENGINE;`

Comment: Data MB 3747.6, Index MB 77.0, Total MB 3824.6, Num Tables 435

Comment: @MichalČerný - Update `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 6G.  It is likely to help with I/O significantly, plus CPU to some extent.

Comment: ulimit -a https://gist.github.com/thiscodeworks/8dcf0c2f1e035c5fdcf04f82be3275f0

Comment: Anyway guys, after some changes to config and tables, fixing some slowlog queries .. server have now avgload 0.3 from 3+, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Lowering this (or turning off the QC) may help performance:

```
query_cache_size = 50M
```

The slowlog is where we can find the villain.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

This one will probably be in the slowlog:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  `cars`
    WHERE  `country` = 'cz'
      and  `status` = 1
      and  `hidden` = 0
      and  `producer_text` = 'Opel'
      and  `source` = '351'
      and  `id` != '129774'
    ORDER BY  rand()
    LIMIT  4
```

`cars` would benefit from this composite index:

```
INDEX(country, status, hidden, producer_text, source)
```

(The order of the columns is not critical.)  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE cars` for further critique.)

Comment: I would like to share the whole table structure but not publicly, is there way to share it with you securely? Thanks

Comment: I will just share it and than remove it after some ciritque :) I added indexes to keys that should have it, thanks! https://gist.github.com/thiscodeworks/0caf998eadfd9f52bd95719fd4afc9c8

Comment: A VIN is 17 chars.  Is `photos` a list of URLs?  Don't use 4-byte `INT` for flags.  `TINYINT` is 1 byte.  Indexes on flags are rarely useful.  (Composite indexes may be more useful.).  If "price" is a `VARCHAR`, it is hard to do arithmetic or range comparisons.  Ditto for `km`?  Meanwhile, the index I proposed should work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G  # from default of 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8  # from 1 to avoid contention
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 default to conserve 90% cpu cycles used for function
```

Let us know if this improves your performance, please.

Comment: (Since the server seems to be CPU-bound, these changes, while beneficial, may not help a lot.)

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Additional suggestions (2021 05 20 05:33 AM local) to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
net_buffer_length=96K  # from 16K to reduce interrupts for packet mgmt
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 651,757
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 27,273
thread_handling=pool-of-threads  # from one-thread-per-connection to utilize thread_pool_size of 6
```

There are other opportunities to improve performance.

Observations from data provided,
handler_rollback averages 1 every 8 seconds indicating deadlocks are prevalent and
need to be resolved to conserve CPU and other expensive cycles.
Select_scan averages 8 RPS indicating additional appropriate indexes are needed.
Slow Query Log Analysis would provide data to assist with corrective action.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider related to your ulimit -a report of Open Files limited to 1024 (2021 05 22 6:40 AM local time).

From OS Command prompt,
ulimit -n 64000 and press Enter to enable additional Open File handles.
This is a dynamic variable and will be available with instance stop/start.

For this setting to persist across OS stop/start see the following URL. https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

- your OS specifics may be slightly different.  Do NOT use 500,000 as listed in this URL, please.  Your goal is 64000 open files.

Suggestions for your my.cnf [mysqld] section to better utilize the changed capacity.

```
table_open_cache_instances=16  # from 8 to reduce Open Table contention
table_definition_cache=1000  # from 400 to reduce opened_table_definitions RPHr of 17
open_files_limit=50000  # from 32188 to increase concurrent open limit
```

There are additional opportunities to improve your instance performance.